# Snackbar not showing instantly

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to save a image when an ImageView is clicked. Because the saving takes some time i want to have some sort of indicator, that the app is working. I tried to use Snackbar for that. My code looks something like this:

```
File image = new File(directory, "image.png");

        if(!image.exists()){

            Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.some_layout), "snackText", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            bar.show();

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
               outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
               outStream.flush();
               outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bar.dismiss();
        }
```

All that is inside the `public void onClick(View view)` of that ImageView. 
The problem is, that the Snackbar only shows after the image is saved. I tried to force update the UI with invalidate() and tried it without starting a new Thread with the same result. 
Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Snack bar is not made for loading indicator, as much i know about it, snackbar will automatically dismiss after some time and the last thing is you code which saving file is added in separate thread, so when you do t.start(); it start that thread but just after it finds bar.dismiss(); and it will dismiss snackbar

Comment: The thing is the code which is out of the thread is independent of that thread this will never wait for thread to be executed, outer code runs on separate thread and inner one runs on separate thread

Comment: You should use dialog in that case

Comment: If you're running this code on the main thread then the problem is clear, you should run computation intensive tasks and IO on a background thread, if you block the UI thread the snackbar doesn't have a chance to be shown before the operation on the file has finished.

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for this problem.Show snack bar on preExecute method.Do you work in doingBackground .After file is save or your task is complete hide the snackbar on postExecute method.

Comment: @umerfarooq Thats exactly what i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use snackbar here edit your code like this:
if(!image.exists()){

```
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog =ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Please Wait...", true);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }

        });
        t.start();

        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```